# Convert UNIX timestamp to date using VueJS

Tags: vue.js, aem

I am working in AEM as a Cloud Service. In that, using query builder I'm getting jcr:created date of the pages through Servlet. To call that servlet, I'm using Vue JS. Now, the date returned by the servlet is in UNIX format. I want to convert that into date format using VueJS.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following statement:

```js
vueJSdate = new Date(unixTimestamp * 1000);
```

UNIX timestamps are in seconds while `Date()` expects milliseconds - so we just multiply by 1000. Keep in mind that the resulting date will be in your local timezone - not in the timezone of the server/database.